# Tor instructions don't work for Bionic Beaver

Tags: software-installation, 18.04, tor

I'm trying to install Tor on Ubuntu the way that the Tor website says and I'm getting nowhere. I added these to the first file then the second then both at the same time.

- You need to add the following entry in `/etc/apt/sources.list` or a new file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`:

  ```
  deb https://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org bionic main
  deb-src https://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org bionic main
  ```

Then went to add the gpg but that didn't work the first command just sat on a blank terminal line for about 5 minutes then basically timed out. Saying it didn't get anything and the second didn't work without the first.

- Then add the gpg key used to sign the packages by running the following commands at your command prompt:

  ```
  gpg --keyserver keys.gnupg.net --recv A3C4F0F979CAA22CDBA8F512EE8CBC9E886DDD89
  gpg --export A3C4F0F979CAA22CDBA8F512EE8CBC9E886DDD89 | sudo apt-key add -
  ```

Has anyone used these instructions and made it work or have any ideas on how to make it work?

Comment: I'm not farmiliar with doing that so I'm at a disadvantage. I tried that earlier. During the "make" command it told me I need to install a few things and gave me commands. I did that the "make" was successful and i went to use it where the website told me but nothing and then I tried the "make install" it said successful but still couldn't launch it.